# how to initialize table with default value in sqlite using ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, sqlite, phonegap

I want to to create a table for 1st time with some n number of rows. This table will be created for the first time user start the app. 
Later this table will be used to just retrieved the saved values. There will be no update, insert or delete query require later.

**My Approach is this.**

Below code is under app.js.

```
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova'])

    .run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {    
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unit (id INTEGER, icon TEXT, unit text)");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "insert into unit (id, icon, unit) values  (1, 'fa fa-inr', 'inr') ");  
                    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'SELECT * from unit', []).then(function(result){
                      /*if table is empty then insert dafault data into it*/
                       if(result.rows.length == 0){ 
                        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "insert into unit (id, unit) values  (1, 'inr') ");
                        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "insert into unit (id, unit) values  (2, 'usd') ");
                        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "insert into unit (id, unit) values  (3, 'euro') ");
                        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "insert into unit (id, unit) values  (4, 'yen') ");
                       }
                    });
    })
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })
})
```

But I think, when ever user start the app, this code execute. 
Is there any way we can avoid this code every time user start the app?

Comment: Need more code. When you are running this code? Where you written this code?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect I have updated the code.This code is inside app.js.

Comment: Please do `console.log(    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unit (id INTEGER, icon TEXT, unit text)"))` first time opening app and second time opening app. Let me know the result

Comment: If it logs respone with some data,we can use that data to proceed further to execute/stop executing the next lines of code